# google play payment flow authentication error

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api

Hi I am trying to test my inapp purchases. I have set up a merchant account, and created an alpha group of testers. However when I try initiate a payment on the app on my device I receive the following error. I have tested this on 2 different devices and I get the same error, although I am able to downnload other apps.

> Error
>   Authentication is required. You need to sign in to your Google Account.

Please help

```
    mHelper.startSetup(new IabHelper.OnIabSetupFinishedListener() {
        public void onIabSetupFinished(IabResult result) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup finished.");

            if (!result.isSuccess()) {
                // Oh noes, there was a problem.
                complain("Problem setting up in-app billing: " + result);
                return;
            }

            // Have we been disposed of in the meantime? If so, quit.
            if (mHelper == null) return;

            // IAB is fully set up. Now, let's get an inventory of stuff we own.
            Log.d(TAG, "Setup successful. Querying inventory.");
            try {
                mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(mGotInventoryListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                complain("Error querying inventory. Another async operation in progress.");
            }
        }
    });

   //Querying for Items Available for Purchase
   IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Purchase gasPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS);
        if (gasPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(gasPurchase)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "We have gas. Consuming it.");
            try {
                mHelper.consumeAsync(inventory.getPurchase(SKU_GAS), mConsumeFinishedListener);
            } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
                complain("Error consuming gas. Another async operation in progress.");
            }
            return;
        }

        //updateUi();
        //setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
   };

   // User clicked the "Buy Gas" button
   public void onBuyCoinButtonClicked(View arg0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Buy coin button clicked.");

    Log.d(TAG, "Launching purchase flow for coins.");

    String payload = "";

    try {
        mHelper.launchPurchaseFlow(this, SKU_GAS, RC_REQUEST,
                mPurchaseFinishedListener, payload);
    } catch (IabHelper.IabAsyncInProgressException e) {
        complain("Error launching purchase flow. Another async operation in progress.");
        //setWaitScreen(false);
    }
}
```

My source is from the trivial drive sample  https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

Comment: check your BASE64APP Id and it it vaild not?

Comment: hi thanks the base64app Id was incorrect, I have corrected it however I still get the error.

Comment: can you put error log here!!??

Comment: there are no error in the logcat when i receive that error

Comment: you are receiving in In app dialog??

Comment: yes in app dialog... I will post my code and screenshot

Comment: please show me your .java file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116365/discussion-between-vishal-patoliya-and-the-big-blackbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1 :Check your base 64 key**

**Step 2: check your Sku**

```
static final String SKU_GAS = "android.test.purchased";
```